# Is there a network communication protocol whose use won't require an app's user to grant permissions in Windows Firewall?

Tags: networking, network-programming

I want my client program to communicate with a server without making the user add an exception to Windows Firewall in elevated mode. Is there a way to do this? HTTP? For instance, uTorrent and Google Chrome can both be installed by a regular (non-admin) user, and both programs network quite extensively - how do they do this? Am I missing something about how the firewall and/or ports works?

Comment: It's generally one thing for an app to "reach out" and do stuff on the network. but setting up a listening service for other apps to reach "in" is another thing entirely. Chrome can be installed by regular users because the default install will go into the user's profile directory, not into \program files, which'd require admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way. Assuming that your client program is the one running on the users machine and that your client program is the one initiating communication with the server  then your client program generally would not need to require end user to open any exceptions in the windows firewall as long as you stick to using http over port 80. Http on port 80 is generally open for outbound traffic (initiated by the client) and therefor you could build your communication (and if needed your own protocol) on top of the http protocol. This is the typical scenario for webserver and webbrowsers (clients).

If you need the server to initiate the communication it becomes more complex and a lot of different approaches could be used. Choice of communication channels and structure should depend on factors like whether you would want to communicate to one client at a time or many (broadcast/multicast), do you need encryption, what are your needs for speed (throughput and latency), what kind of system are you trying to build and so on.

Many webapplications achieve an effect of a server initiated communication by using special techniques called polling, long polls, comet, websockets and so on. these work through http on top of tcp/ip on port 80. Other systems employs subscription mechanisms to be able to get notified through a third part if something new has happened. If you need server initiated communications please let me now and i will try to give a better explanation on the options.

Comment: Yeah, so how would one set up a server-initiated system?

Comment: If your system is webbased you could perhaps use websockets [link](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/) or use a thirdparty system to relay messages. I have not tried [link](www.pusher.com)www.pusher.com myself, but it seems useful for websystems, that need to communicate with many clients in a highly scalable way. [link] http://pusher.com/tutorials. These are only a few options, it really depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you can give a bit more information. Maybe I or others could give you a more concrete answer. Hope this helps you out.